# What is the use of exits present in IBM Websphere MQ ? Could anyone quote some real time example where it will be used?

Tags: websphere, ibm-mq, mq

I am currently working with IBM MQ 7.0 and we have never used exits and I need to know in which scenario it can be best used. Needed some real time example where it will be used ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Exits are simply points in the processing of the QMgr or channel that can call out to user-defined code.  Some common examples include:

- Use a client/server exit pair to provide client credentials which are validated by the server-side.
- Use a Message Exit to set message options (like turn off report options).
- Use a connection exit to perform workload balancing of clients.
- Use a workload balancing exit to choose destinations for messages in a cluster.
- Use an API exit to capture and log message content moving through the QMgr.
- Use an OAM exit to change the behavior of OAM (for example authorize against LDAP instead of SYSTEM.AUTH.DATA.QUEUE).

In general, WMQ does what you need it to do without the need for exits.  However, if you do need some functionality WMQ does not provide, an exit can often help.  Just be aware that WMQ exits on the server side are system-level C code that must be re-entrant, relocatable and thread safe because they share memory with the QMgr.